# Integrando artigos a um slider

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, slider

Estou a trabalhar num slider de artigos, cujo estes artigos estão numa database podendo ser eleminados/adicionados (CMS), está tudo a trabalhar na perfeição, a database, e o slider. Agora só queria integrar os artigos no slider. Aqui está o meu código, o que está a acontecer é que os artigos estão a aparecer todos ao mesmo tempo uns em cima dos outros, alguma dica?

JS:

```
sliderInt=1;
sliderNext=2;
$("#newsText > p#1").fadeIn(500);
startSlider();

function startSlider() {
    count = $("#newsText > p").size();
    loop = setInterval (function() {
        if (sliderNext>count) {     
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

    $("#newsText > p").fadeOut(500);
    $("#newsText > p#" + sliderNext).delay(500).fadeIn(500);
    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext ++;

    } ,7500);
}

function stopLoop() {
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

function showSlide(id) {
    stopLoop();
        if (id>count) {       
            id = 1;
      }
        else if (id<1) {
            id=count;
      }

    $("#newsText > p").fadeOut(500);
    $("#newsText > p#" + id).fadeIn(500);

    sliderInt = id;
    sliderNext = id + 1;
    startSlider();
}
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once('php/CMS/includes/connection.php');
include_once('php/CMS/includes/article.php');

?>
.......HTML....
<?php 

                for ($id=1; $id < count($articles); $id++) {
                    echo ("<p id=".$id.">".$articles[$id]['article_content']."</p>");
                }

            ?>
```

Comment: Fiz o update da pergunta em cima... o que está a acontecer é que os artigos estão a aparecer todos ao mesmo tempo uns em cima dos outros

Comment: Ao que me parece o JavaScript está mandando o slideshow começar antes dos slides terem sido carregados. Já tentou colocar o JavaScript no final da página ou chamar a função `startSlider();` dentro de um `$(document).load(callback)`?

Comment: O javascript está no final, e se houver tags 'p' estáticas com ids numerados a partir do 1 funciona muito bem, eu acho que o erro é no php. Obgado

Comment: Agora que eu notei: pq vc está atribuindo o mesmo `id` em todas as divs? Por definição, você não pode ter `id`s com o mesmo nome em uma página. Tire aquele `foreach` que está fora do `for` e use apenas o contador do `for` nos nomes dos `id`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está nesse trecho de código:

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    for ($articles=0; $articles <= count($articles); $articles++) {
         $id = 1;
         echo ("<p id =".$id++.">".$article['article_content']."</p>");
    }
}
```

Tire o `foreach` que está fora do `for` e use apenas o contador do `for` para incrementar os `id`s das `div`s. Por definição, você não pode ter elementos com o mesmo `id` em uma página HTML.

Sugestão de correção:

```
$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();
for ($i=0, $count=sizeof($articles); $i<$count; $i++) {
     echo ("<p id='article_".$i."'>".$articles[$i]['article_content']."</p>");
}
```

Comment: Mas se eu tirar o foreach dá erro (Cannot use object of type Article as array in C:\WebS...), não consegue identificar

Comment: @Miguel Dá erro porque você está declarando uma variável `$article` no começo do código. Aquilo é desnecessário, tire essa linha e o `foreach`, deixando apenas o `for`. Fiz uma sugestão de correção, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Não resultou, porque a classe Article é que está a ir buscar o $article['article_content'] à base de dados mysql. O problema não é dar erro, creio que é só logica na parte do php, pois os artigos aparecem, mas aparecem todos ao mesmo tempo

Comment: @Miguel É verdade, eu não havia notado a linha de baixo. Como eu disse, o problema é que todos os elementos estavam com o mesmo `id`. Coloque a sugestão de correção que eu dei e tente de novo :)

Comment: Deu "Undefined offset: 4 in C:\WebS..." na linha do echo. fiz o seu update em cima

Comment: Tirei o "<p id='article_".$i..." e deixai só o "<p id = .$i....." já está a funcionar mas o erro contnua na linha do echo, apesar de o slider já estar perfeito

Comment: @Miguel Fiz mais uma correção no código: não é para ter um `<=` no `for`, apenas um `<`. (se o seu array de artigos possui 4 elementos, o `for` deve ir de 0 a 3; o elemento 4 estaria indefinido). Se funcionou, não esqueça de dar um ok na resposta :)

Comment: Muito Obrigado @rodrigo